# Image Animation Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

I have 7 images I want to animate on my Joomla site, I want to give the impression of them coming in from the left and all stopping in the middle of the page, they are then clickable and go to an individual url menu item.

Is this possible, does someone have a script for this where I can call the images.

I mean to learn jQuery as soon as I can but in need of putting images on site.

Any help well appreciated.

Thanks

Dil

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://daneden.me/animate/) and [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) sites.

These links contains information about keyframes and css which will be best suited for your requirement. choose any effect you want.

[Here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/css3-animated-scene/) you can find some demos.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I see the keyframe codes but where do I add my images and how do I call them in the index.php/css files

Comment: Would this work?<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> function animateImage() { console.log("Called"); $('#bee').css({right:'10%'}); $('#bee').animate({right: '-100%'}, 5000, 'linear', function(){animateImage();}); } $(document).ready(function() { animateImage(); }); </script> </head> <body> <div style="width: 100%;"><img src="myimage1.jpg" id="bee" style="position:relative;"/></div> </body> </html>

Comment: I dont see anything? if I add a script into the index.php head and enter the images into the body of the index.php is that the way to go? thanks

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to add several images to my index.php whereby they each come onto the page one by one and then all stop. The images should have links so are clickable to each url for a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be used? is it a start? what path in the web root would the image path be for jQuery?
Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
     $(window).load(function(){

    $("<div/>", {
      "id": "image",
      "css": { "display" : "block"},
    }).appendTo("body");

    $("<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/image1.png'/>").appendTo("#image");
    $("<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/image2.png'/>").appendTo("#image");
    $("<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/image3.png'/>").appendTo("#image");
    $("<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/image4.png'/>").appendTo("#image");
    $("<img src='_ls-global/layout-images/image5.png'/>").appendTo("#image");

    });

</body>
</html>
```